# Cookie written in JavaScript not being read in code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

`Response.Cookies["alertsCookie"]` gives me a blank cookie.

I have made two cookies since I could not find out how to read a cookie in a path, so I decided to write them to both locations (the page path and /)

Code-behind:

```
HttpCookie seenAlertsCookie = Response.Cookies["alertsCookie"];
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
var cookie = $.cookie("alertsCookie");
alert(cookie);
if (cookie == null) {
    $.cookie('alertsCookie', alertGuid, { expires: 7300, path: '/' });
    $.cookie('alertsCookie', alertGuid, 7300);

}
else {
    var cookieVal = cookie + '|';
    cookieVal = cookieVal + alertGuid;
    $.cookie('alertsCookie', cookieVal, { expires: 7300, path: '/' });
    $.cookie('alertsCookie', cookieVal, 7300);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look in `Request` instead of `Response`.

```
HttpCookie seenAlertsCookie = Request.Cookies["alertsCookie"];
```

`Response.Cookies` is for setting cookies on the browser, `Request.Cookies` is for reading cookies coming from the browser.